# separating <th> elements in a table

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make list of mobile phones website and this is the actual problem look at the screenshot here is the codes too thml and css files `<th>`s must be separated by border this is the picture :    [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3A7S.png]

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mobile phones</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <h1>eMobile</h1>

    <div id="wid">
        <input type="text" name="manuf" value="დასახელება"></br>
        <select>
            <option value="none">მწარმოებელი</option>
            <option value="nokia">Nokia</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Samsung</option>
            <option value="sony">Sony</option>
        </select> </br>
     ფილტრაცია ფასით</br>
    დან:<input type="number" name="from" value="0"> მდე:<input type="number" name="to_the" value="99999">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><img src="2058.jpg"> </br>  <h5>Lumia 1520 Black</h5></th>
            <th><img src="2058.jpg"> </br>  <h5>Lumia 1520 Black</h5></th>
        </tr>
    </table>        
</html>
```

css

```
body {
    background-color: #66CCFF
}
h1 {
    color: black;
    border-bottom:solid #2A1959;
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
}
select {
    width:173px;
}
tr,td {
    height=300px;
    width=200px;
    border:2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 30px;
    colspan="0"
}      
table {
    height:500px;
    width:800px;
    border:3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 330px;
    z-index: -1;
}      
#wid {
    width: 200px;
    height: 600px;
    border-right:solid #2A1959;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
#wid div {
    position: relative;
    top: 500px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `border` to separate `th`

```
th {
font-weight: bold;
border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

### **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/0awqonp5/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

remove tr border property and set border for th , td :

```
th ,td {
border: 3px solid black;
}
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z12nbLfx/1/)